# How to do mongodb $lookup, but keep other fields

Tags: mongodb

Each document in my collection has a list of people and their status:

```
[
  {
    _id: 61c005f839d7239960dced76,
    people: [
      { id: 61c005b939d7239960dceca5, status: 'pending' },
      { id: 6204232e0aa660002e2e2617, status: 'active' }
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

I do a lookup to replace the person ID with the actual data from another collection, with this lookup stage:

```
{                                                                 
  $lookup: {                                                      
    from: 'user',                                                 
    let: { people: '$people' },                                   
    pipeline: [ 
      { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ '$_id', '$$people.id' ] } } }
    ],                                                            
    as: 'people'                                                 
  }                                                               
}
```

The result of this is something like this:

```
[
  { 
    _id: 61c005f839d7239960dced76,
    people: [
      {
        _id: 61c005b939d7239960dceca5,
        lastName: 'Joe',
        firstName: 'Shmo',
      },
      {
        _id: 6204232e0aa660002e2e2617,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Appleseed',
      }
    ]
  },
  // ...
]
```

That's great, but I've lost the "status" field from the original documents.
Is there a way to keep the status field in the result? Or copy it in afterward?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to move status to the people collection but if you want to keep it and you are fine with having following structure

```
"people": {
   "data": {
       "_id": 100,
       "lastName": "...",
       "firstName": "..."
   },
   "status": "active"
}
```

I can suggest using `$unwind`

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$people"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "people",
      "localField": "people.id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "people.data"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { // this one is used to remove duplicate id, can be skipped
      "people.data": 1,
      "people.status": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$people.data"
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gRLzpJ3i6Ir

Not very efficient...

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "user",
      let: {
        people: "$people"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [
                "$_id",
                "$$people.id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "people2"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "people": {
        $map: {
          input: "$people2",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$people",
                      "as": "pstatus",
                      "cond": {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$pstatus.id",
                          "$$this._id"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```